# Dependency Injection Syntax

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

I'm trying to build a simple module (to learn DI) to return the current user ID, and and apparently I'm missing something in the syntax.

Here's my code and the error it's producing:

```
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

 class LSWController {
  /**
   * @var AccountProxy
   */ 
     protected $currentUser;

     public function __construct(AccountProxyInterface $currentUser) {
         $this->currentUser = $currentUser;
     }

     public function say() {
         return new Response("Hello");
        //return new Response($this->currentUser->id());
     }
 }
```

and the error

ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Drupal\lsw\Controller\LSWController::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\wamp64\www\testdrupal\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver.php on line 31 and exactly 1 expected in Drupal\lsw\Controller\LSWController->__construct()

What am I missing?  I'm including the AccountProxyInterface, etc.  How come it's saying that 0 arguments are being passed?

Answer (score 5):

Classes aren't naturally aware of the container, you have to implement them in such a way that they are. The most common approach for controllers is to extend `Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase`, and override the `create` method, e.g.

```
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class LSWController extends ControllerBase {
  /**
   * @var AccountProxy
   */ 
   protected $currentUser;

   public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
     return new static($container->get('current_user'));
   }

   public function __construct(AccountProxyInterface $currentUser) {
     $this->currentUser = $currentUser;
   }

   public function say() {
     return new Response("Hello");
     //return new Response($this->currentUser->id());
   }
}
```

For you, though, this approach will be bittersweet...on the one hand you've learned how to inject services into a controller, which is great.

On the other hand, `ControllerBase` already has a `$currentUser` property, which resolves to the same object you'd be getting from the injected service. So in applying the common solution, you've removed your original need for DI, and made the `create` and constructor methods completely redundant ;)

As 4k4 very correctly points out in a comment, you don't have to extend `ControllerBase`; implementing `ContainerInjectionInterface` in your own controller class is enough. But the deliciousness of solving the problem with less code than when you started is surely too much to resist.

Comment: Even if you use ControllerBase you can still inject the service to the existing property if you want to have a proper DI. ControllerBase is then only like a fallback which loads the service statically if not already injected when initialized.

Comment: Yep good point @4k4

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject the services through a public static function called create. In your case something like this:

```
   /**
   * @param \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container
   *
   * @return static
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('current_user')
    );
  }
```

The services you load through the container should match those in your `_construct` function

Comment: Yes, create() is exactly what is missing for DI, but in a controller you need `class LSWController implements ContainerInjectionInterface`. Otherwise the class resolver won't find create().

Comment: Yes you're right, I missed that in the code the OP posted :)